# How can I implement a setter for an abstract property in Python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, setter

I have an abstract class `A` which has a property for which I need to have a variable listener/setter:

```py
class A(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
  @property
  @abc.abstractmethod
  def someData(self):
    pass

  # and several other functions which may or may not modify "someData"
```

The value to the field `someData` is being assigned in some of the derived classes. For the other derived classes, the field's value is defined by functions in `A` itself which are called by the derived class.

If I try doing something like this, ...

```py
class A(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
  @property
  @abc.abstractmethod
  def someData(self):
    pass

  @someData.setter
  def someData(self, val):
    self.someData = val
```

... the setter is only called when the value of `someData` is changing within some function in `A` itself. If `someData` is assigned a value in one of the derived classes, it does not call the setter function.

How can I implement a setter for an abstract property (I need the setter to be called irrespective of whether the property is being assigned a value in one of the derived classes or in the abstract class)?

Comment: Considering how rare it is that you would need an abstract class in python, you may want to consider if what you really need is just a class that you extend and potentially override in parts.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry, I'm sure my use case requires abstract classes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias that subclasses should not override, which calls a setter that subclasses *should* override:

```
class A(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
  @property
  @abc.abstractmethod
  def someData(self):
    pass

  @someData.setter
  def _setSomeData(self, val):
      self.setSomeData(val)

  def setSomeData(self, val):
    self._someData = val
```

Since `self.someData` is determined at runtime, not at compile-time, then as long as a subclass only overrides the `someData()` method, it will always get used as the 'actual' setter.

Usually when using this pattern, the externally-visible variable name is `someData`, but the internal name is `_someData`. Because `_someData` is not a @property, it can be get and set the normal way, without infinitely recurring. You would then proceed to also make a getter:

```
  @someData.getter
  def _getSomeData(self)
    return self.getSomeData()

  getSomeData(self):
    return self._someData
```

Comment: So this would require me to explicitly override the function `someData()` in my derived class? I can't directly assign a value to `someData` in my derived class, as can be done with other class properties?

Comment: @Shreya it would work like any other method - can be ignored and left as is, or can be overwritten to get different behavior if you want (if the subclass doesn't override it explicitly, then of course it just uses the superclass's implicit implementation). Although you might want to also have two versions of the variable: `someData` the property, and `_someData`, an instance variable that _isn't_ a property but which the setter and getter use to hold the actual value that they return. I'll edit that into my answer.